# Searching Bookmarks

Tags: feature-request, support, bookmarks

I have a moderate number of bookmarked questions (around 30-40), and like the idea of adding more. This will let me "pin" items of interest.

However, I noticed that bookmarked are listed and can only be browsed. Is there a way to "search" in your bookmarks?

Comment: TL;DR: look for "To search within your bookmarks" in the duplicate question.